# How to get parameters from the Angular ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

I'm trying to get the prameter :id from my activated route using observables. When I print params on the console I get the right values for :id. But it's not the case for this.id. I get the value NaN.
Can you tell me what is the problem

```
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  editMode = false;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: {id: string}) => {
        this.id = +params.id;
        console.log(this.id);
      }
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Could you put that code into your question as code block and not as image.

Comment: what you get if you console.log(params.id)?

Comment: Undifined
Even though I'm getting the right object when I print params
the object with :id = 1

Comment: how do you call this route? what is in your browsers address bar?

Comment: the route is : 
{ path: '::id/edit', component: RecipeEditComponent}
The link in the browser is:
http://localhost:4200/recipes/0/edit

Comment: Is double colon :: a typo? Try with single one.

Comment: @robert1 yes this was the problem thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change to `this.id = +params.get('id')`.

You should use the method `get()` because it returns a single value for the given parameter `id`.
You were getting an error because `params` is not a key with `id` as a value.

```
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  editMode = false;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  // paramMap replaces params in Angular v4+
   this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params: ParamMap => {
        this.id = +params.get('id');
        console.log(this.id);     
  });
}
```

Comment: it shows this error: 
ERROR TypeError: "params.get is not a function"

Comment: If you are using Angular v4+, change `params` to `paramMap`.

Comment: I've changed it to paramMap
but now it does print nothing on the console

Comment: Do you have the `console.log(this.id)` in the code?

Comment: Yes, now it prints 0 as value for 'this.id'
But when I print params it gives me an object with the right values of 'id'

Comment: Why is there a + sign ? I haven't found anything on the documentation about it.

Comment: @Ellone The + sign changes the id from a string to a number.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code is going to work in your case:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.heroes$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  switchMap(params => {
    // (+) before `params.get()` turns the string into a number
    this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
    return this.service.getHeroes();
  })
);
```

}

Also you can try this:

```
this.sessionId = this.route
  .queryParamMap
  .pipe(map(params => params.get('id') || 'None'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the params like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(
  (params: Params) => {
    this.id = +params["id"];
    console.log(this.id);
  }
);
```

}
}

Comment: maybe try this: `Number(params["id"])`

Answer (score 1):

id: number;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.id = this.route.snapshot.params(['id'])

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the route definition:
putting : instead of ::