# Can't get query parameters from ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a route defined like this in the routing module:

```
{ path: 'warning/:type', component: WarningPageComponent }
```

When the app wants to navigate to the warning page this call is made:

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParamsHandling: 'preserve',
        queryParams: { errorCode: '12345'}
      };
return this.router.navigate(['/warning/default'],navigationExtras);
```

In the `WarningPageComponent` the parameters are read like this `ngOnInit()`:

```
const params = this.route.snapshot.paramMap;
console.log('ERR warning page' + JSON.stringify(params));
const errorCode = params.get('errorCode') ?? undefined;
const type = params.get('type') ?? undefined;
```

The problem is now that only the `type` is present in the `paramMap` but not the `errorCode`. What is wrong here? I also tried with `queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'`

Angular 8.2.14

I found no solution in:

- [Angular erasing all query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598762/angular-erasing-all-query-parameters#47598970)
- [Parent components gets empty Params from ActivatedRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947133/parent-components-gets-empty-params-from-activatedroute)
- [How to get parameters from the Angular ActivatedRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524175/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-angular-activatedroute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access queryParams then you have to use queryParamMap on snapshot object.

```
const queryParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap;
const errorCode = queryParams.get('errorCode') ?? undefined;
```

Comment: Can you give some background information in your answer, why it have to be  `queryParamMap` instead of `paramMap`?

Comment: @Chriss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615857/angular-parammap-vs-queryparammap

Answer (score 0):

Do like this get the params inside constructor

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy {
    queryParams: any;
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.queryParams = Utils.paramsToLower(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams);
      }
    }
```